# php Soap client issue (Security header)

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

Uncaught SoapFault exception: [wsse:InvalidSecurity] Missing wsse:Security header in request

Can someone help me to solve this issue.What this error about??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Header>       
  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/06/secext">
   <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="sample" 
       xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/06/utility">
    <wsse:Username>sample</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password Type="wsse:PasswordText">oracle</wsse:Password>
    <wsu:Created>2004-05-19T08:44:51Z</wsu:Created>
   </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
 </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
   <getHello xmlns="http://www.oracle.com"/>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Every SOAP Request need to have header and sometime it authentication is required , it needs some predefined headers.

Comment: @anwerjunaid how can i know the headers?..anyway to find them?

Answer (score 0):

This is common structure with two usertokens, you may need to use one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Header>       
  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/06/secext">
   <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="sample" 
       xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/06/utility">
    <wsse:Username>sample</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password Type="wsse:PasswordText">oracle</wsse:Password>
    <wsu:Created>2004-05-19T08:44:51Z</wsu:Created>
   </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
  <wsse:Security soap:actor="oracle" 
      xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/06/secext">
   <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="oracle" 
       xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/06/utility">
    <wsse:Username>oracle</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password Type="wsse:PasswordText">oracle</wsse:Password>
    <wsu:Created>2004-05-19T08:46:04Z</wsu:Created>
   </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
 </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
   <getHello xmlns="http://www.oracle.com"/>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

You need to modify your request to this format.

Comment: still it says "Missing wsse:Security header in request"..why?

Comment: Try to change the attribute to format given API providers, which ever API you are using.